# XRDP with Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: server, 20.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

I am using an Ubuntu 20.04 Webserver and followed the tutorial [Here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-20-04/) to set up XRDP and am trying to use Windows Remote Desktop to connect to the server and give it a GUI.

The install seemed to go fine and when I enter the IP of the server into Windows remote Desktop, it finds it and prompts me for my login details

After entering my login details the remote desktop window opens with a black screen and then instantly closes.

This is my first time attempting to use XRDP or similar.

Is there a recommended method to debug the issue?
Given that the Remote Desktop Window closes I am assuming it will be something on the desktop end rather than the server but I could be wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: @user68186 I logged out of ssh/sftp and plesk and tried again but got the same outcome.

Comment: I was not talking about logging out of ssh/sftp or plesk. I was talking about logging out of the desktop GUI such as "(X)Ubuntu Desktop". If you have monitor, keyboard, mouse, etc. connected to the web server, logout using those things. Which desktop did you install: the Ubuntu desktop, or the Xubuntu desktop?

Comment: @user68186 I have installed the Gnome Desktop, i have reinstalled XRDP and it is now working. Very slow though

Comment: Someone has [written a script](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=17994) that installs xrdp and tweaks it. As with any script, you should read everything (including the script) and make sure that you understand it and it is safe before you give it a try.